# Jenkins Deployment to Staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, engineyard

I'm trying to find a way for Jenkins to deploy to my staging server on Engine Yard when all all tests have passed? Are there any plugin for this post-build action from Jenkins?

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider creating build pipeline https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin
One build to build & test and another for deployment (or maybe more to deploy to staging automatically if tests pass and do third step - deploy to next environment triggered manually).

-Radim

Answer (score 1):

[engineyard-jenkins](https://github.com/engineyard/engineyard-jenkins) looks like it will do the trick.